# Data modelling ( secondary index vs clustering key )

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I am trying to understand if it's going to be a performance issue if I choose
OPTION 1:
 very high unique value column as partition key ( order_id), and create indexes on store_id and status.  ( i can query on order_id | store_id | status | both store&status , and also ***update(important) status based on order_id)

Option 2:
 store_id as partition_key and very high unique value column as clustering key ( order_id) and create secondary index on status ( so that i can filter on status)
( I can query on store_id | store&order_id | store&status | and also **update status based on store&order_id )

I would like to know what will be the performance issues in above scenarios. which one will be a better option. Thank you very much for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** is interesting, but you need to be careful with your indices. See your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31013238/maximum-secondary-indexes-on-a-columnfamily/31014715#31014715) for more information there (especially the bit concerning querying multiple secondary indices at the same time). That may be alleviated with [tables purpose built for your index lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124993/how-to-avoid-secondary-indexes-in-cassandra) (further discussed below).

The advantage of the highly unique partition key is that data will be more distributed around your cluster. The downside here is that when you perform a request with `WHERE store_id = 'foo'` all nodes in the cluster need to be queried as there is no limit on the partition key.

**Option 2** you must be careful with. If your partition key is just store_id, then every order will be placed within this partition. For each order there will be *n* columns added to the single row for the store representing each attribute on the order. In regards to data location all orders for a given store will be placed on the same Cassandra node.

In both cases why not pursue a lookup table for orders by status? This will remove your need for a secondary index on that field. Especially given it's relatively small cardinality.

```
CREATE TABLE orders_by_store_id_status (
  store_id VARCHAR,
  status   VARCHAR,
  order_id VARCHAR,
  ... <additional order fields needed to satisfy your query> ...
  PRIMARY KEY ((store_id, status), order_id)
);
```

This would allow you to query for all orders with a given store_id and status.

`SELECT * FROM orders_by_store_id_status WHERE store_id = 'foo' AND status = 'open';`

The read is fast as the partition key limits the number of nodes we perform the query against.